# XSLT Dynamically merge two xml files using filter on element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt, I have two xml files as follows file1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-data id="test-id" timestamp="20014-03-30T09:00:00">
   <person>
      <id>12345</id>
      <first-name>John</first-name>
   </person>

   <person>
      <id>67890</id>
      <first-name>Mike</first-name>
   </person>

   <person>
      <id>11111</id>
      <first-name>Dan</first-name>
   </person>
</people-data>
```

The second xml file is as follows file2.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<people-appointment-data>
    <person-data>        
        <id>12345</id>
        <first-name>John</first-name>       
        <appointments>
          <appointment>
            <code>5124</code>
            <pass>14920329324</pass>
            <states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>IN</state>
            </states>
         </appointment>

          <appointment>
            <code>1001</code>
            <pass>14921119324</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
         </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
<person-data>        
    <id>67890</id>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>       
    <appointments>
        <appointment>
            <code>6666</code>
            <pass>14920</pass>
            <states>
                <state>AK</state>
                <state>MA</state>
            </states>
        </appointment>
    </appointments>
</person-data>
</people-appointment-data>
```

What I am trying to achieve using xslt is to copy the appointments information into the first xml file, filtering a match on id tag.

This is how I am expecting the output to be if there is no match on id the information in file1.xml will be retained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people-data id="test-id" timestamp="20014-03-30T09:00:00">
   <person>
      <id>12345</id>
      <first-name>John</first-name>
      <appointments>
            <appointment>
                <code>5124</code>
                <pass>14920329324</pass>
                <states>
                    <state>IL</state>
                    <state>IN</state>
                </states>
            </appointment>

          <appointment>
            <code>1001</code>
            <pass>14921119324</pass>
            <states>
                <state>NV</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </states>
         </appointment>
        </appointments>
   </person>

   <person>
      <id>67890</id>
      <first-name>Mike</first-name>
      <appointments>
            <appointment>
                <code>6666</code>
                <pass>14920</pass>
                <states>
                    <state>AK</state>
                    <state>MA</state>
                </states>
            </appointment>
        </appointments>
   </person>

   <person>
      <id>11111</id>
      <first-name>Dan</first-name>
   </person>
</people-data>
```

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT you are using - 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Can you guide me on this using XSLT 1.0, the current solution given below doesn't work. @michael.hor257k

Comment: Although the "current solution" is pretty awful, it still should "work" in the sense that it should get the appointments of each person. So I suggest you get things working properly on your side first.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, there was a mistake in my xml file with closing tag. The solution given below is working. What is your suggestion to improve this? I am very new to xslt and still learning. @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="lookup-document" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="pdata" match="person-data" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <people-data>
        <xsl:for-each select="people-data/person">
            <person>
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <!--  switch context to lookup-document in order to use the key -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('pdata', $id)/appointments"/>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </person>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </people-data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I had a query if there are two attribute values that I would like to copy to the merged file for example I have updated the question (id="test-id" timestamp="20014-03-30T09:00:00") how should I modify this solution. I tried using <people-data id="{@id}" timestamp="{@timestamp}"> but it didn't get copied its blank.

Comment: @user2603537 This has absolutely nothing to do with your original question of retrieving data from **another** document; **2.** You can easily solve this by adding a `<xsl:copy-of select="people-data/@*"/>` instruction immediately after `<people-data>`. If this doesn't work for you, I suggest you post a separate question (and close this one).

Answer (score 0):

The document() function will let you match values in an alternate document.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//person"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="copy"/>
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="id/text()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')//person-data[id/text()=$id]/appointments" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: how can you test this, I tried to look for xml/xslt tester online but just came across websites, which allows you to use one xml file as input?

Comment: I have an XML editor / XSLT editor, so I tested this on my file system.  In order to test on the web, you would need both input files to be accessible from a web server.

Comment: Can you please guide me what XML editor/ XSLT editor you are using.

Comment: I have used Oxygen XML Editor and Altova XML Spy.  Eclipse might also offer a plugin for XSLT editing.

Comment: I tried to run the above XSLT, I am using Pentaho for running the xslt. I doesn't seem to work as I wanted.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
   <id>12345</id>
   <first-name>John</first-name>
</person>
<person>
   <id>67890</id>
   <first-name>Mike</first-name>
</person>
<person>
   <id>11111</id>
   <first-name>Dan</first-name>
</person>

Appointments didn't get copied.

Comment: I am not familiar with that tool.  I recommend that you confirm that the document command is opening your second file correctly.  In your root template, try outputting <xsl:value-of select="count(document('file2.xml')//person-data)"/>.  If the count is 0, then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I had problem in the xml file and hence it didnt work. Its working now. Is this a optimum solution, what would be other ways to implement it much better. @terrywb

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you.  What else are you seeking from the solution?

Comment: Having a root element in the output would be a good start, I think.

Comment: I had a query if there are two attribute values that I would like to copy to the merged file for example I have updated the question (id="test-id" timestamp="20014-03-30T09:00:00") how should I modify this solution. I tried using <people-data id="{@id}" timestamp="{@timestamp}"> but it didn't get copied its blank. Can you also recommend for the solution given by michael